# undefined local variable or method `parameter_sanitizer'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rubygems

I keep throwing this error while customizing Devise. Everything seems up to date and I checked the syntax. I am running Devise 4.1 and Rails 4.2.6. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected



  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update) do |user_params| user_params.permit(:email,
  :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :title, :description,
   :itunes, :stitcher, :podbay)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try `devise_permitted_parameters` instead of `desive permitted_parameters`, like this ->

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update) do |user_params| 
    user_params.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :title, :description, :itunes, :stitcher, :podbay)
  end #I think you also missed this 'end'
end
```

Please let me know if worked?

Answer (score 0):

I tinkered and this is what worked for me:

```
 def configure_permitted_parameters
 devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:email, :password, :title])
 devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:email, :password,
 :password_confirmation, :current_password, :title, :description, :itunes, :stitcher, :podbay])
```

end